# Encrypt data with Android Keystore and user provided secret

Tags: android, security, android-keystore

I would like to use the Hardware Android Keystore, to safely encrypt sensitiv data and store it locally on the device. The standard implementation seems very easy and there are enough tutorials out there on how to implement it.

But the requirements I got require that a user provided secret (a user pin or password that the user has to enter) is included into the encryption of the senstive data. So that encryption/decryption of the data only works with the known user secret and not without it.

I haven't found a way to provide a user secret into the Android Keystore process.

How can I encrypt/decrypt data with the Android Keystore that needs a secret user input to actually work?

Comment: You can use the Keystore to encrypt part of the passphrase for another encryption round, where the user-provided secret forms the other part of the passphrase. The combined passphrase can be used with things like SQLCipher for Android.

Comment: Do you mean to create a random passphrase on the device that you would protect with the power of the keystore (persist it by encrypting it with the keystore key) and them combine that with a user provided secred by something like a PBKDF2 of the SecretKeyFactory? And then use that key that we generated with the PBKDF2 to actually encrypt/decrypt our sensitiv data?

Comment: "Do you mean to create a random passphrase on the device that you would protect with the power of the keystore (persist it by encrypting it with the keystore key)" -- yes.  "them combine that with a user provided secred by something like a PBKDF2" -- whether you need key stretching like PBKDF2 rounds would depend on what will use the combined key. For example, SQLCipher for Android already does its own PBKDF2 rounds, so you would not need to add yet more rounds on your own. "And then use that key... to actually encrypt/decrypt our sensitiv data?" -- yes.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AndroidKeyStore` does not provide any API to set user provided password for the generated secret. Only thing that you can do is, setting a [KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationRequired](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.html#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)) flag to `true` for system provided user authentication (pin / pattern / fingerprint etc.. )

The real power of `AndroidKeyStore` is comes from the TEE and Secure Hardware. So that, any other option rather than using the key directly in the `AndroidKeyStore` should be considered as less-secure. So that, generating PBKDF2 using both user provided secret and key store encrypted secret doesn't makes your encryption more secure.  Because, that new key should be managed in an application memory and is vulnerable (of course in compromised device) until you complete encryption and wipe all of the key bytes.

But in secure hardware, `AndroidKeyStore` doesn't even loads your keys in a memory. Every operation happens in a separated secure hardware.

If your requirement is not strictly "having one key" and "encrypt data only once", you may consider to encrypt your data twice using both of the secret from `AndroidKeyStore` and user key which is derived from user password.

And also, you may want to read this paper: http://www.cs.ru.nl/~joeri/papers/spsm14.pdf. In this paper, authors also mention Bouncy Castle keystore with user-provided password.

Comment: Apparently the downside to using `AndroidKeyStore` is not that your keys are insecure but the values you are encrypting can be inspected using a toolkit called [Frida](https://frida.re/docs/android/). If you know enough of the codebase, you can find where that value is used and access the decrypted value.